# Tab change event in Ajax Tab control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback

I have used Ajax Tab Control in one of my pages. It has got a master User Control with three tabs in it.
Those three tabs have been populated by three separate user controls.
Those user controls have some controls and a save button to save data.
My problem is that, I have to stop a user from navigating away from a tab if he has any unsaved changes in the current tabs User control. I have to ask him in a pop up that you have unsaved changes, would you like to save them. And according to response of user have to follow up with further action.
I am able to open Pop up and ask about unsaved changes using OnClientActiveTabChanged event of TabControl. I am facing issue in knowing exactly which tab's data is unsaved. I am not able to track down current tab, from which user is trying to navigate away.Can anybody help me out in maintaining current tab's name all the time, so that whenever user clicks on any other tab i will be knowing which tab's data I have to save and could fire save function of the appropriate user control from my Master User control.

Please find below code sample for the same:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterUserControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="TabbedSolution.MasterUserControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Src="UserControl1.ascx" TagName="UserControl1" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="UserControl2.ascx" TagName="UserControl2" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register Src="UserControl3.ascx" TagName="UserControl3" TagPrefix="uc3" %>
<div>
    <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" OnClientActiveTabChanged="chechUnsavedChanges" OnActiveTabChanged="tabChanged">
        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Panel1" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc1:UserControl1 ID="UserControl11" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="Panel2">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc2:UserControl2 ID="UserControl21" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="Panel3">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc3:UserControl3 ID="UserControl31" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
    </asp:TabContainer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This in your tabchanged javascript function

```
var container = $find('TabContainer1');
var activeTab = container.get_activeTabIndex();
```

I don't know the way without jquery, but why use javascript without jquery huh :)

ps: I haven't tested this solution, but it should work

Comment: Thanks for resolution but still no luck.. 
I tried it.
PFb function:
function checkUnsavedChanges() {

            debugger;
            var container = document.getElementById("<%= TabContainer1.ClientID %>");
            var container1 = $find("<%= TabContainer1.ClientID %>");
            var container2 = $find('TabContainer1');
            var activeTab = container.get_activeTabIndex();
            alert(container);
            alert(container1);
            alert(container2);
        }
No result out of alert

Comment: did you try alert(container.toString()); or alert(JSON.stringify(container)); or alert(activeTab.toString()); maybe if I have some time at the weekend i'll try it out myself, I'm actually at work right now :p

Comment: yeah sure.. No issues. Will try what with .ToString(). Will give it some more try on my end as well..

Comment: Finally this one worked.. Had to fix few more things along with this but this one was key component. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that if you could get the current active tab index and store it in session, that should work. This is what I do for multiview activeviewindex etc. onclick events for asp.net controls. I get the values on the page load complete event to save users current view on refresh etc.

I have found that using the multiview with an update panel and a little graphic genious to make it look like a tab, you can make a tab control that can have clickable link buttons so you can set the session this way.... set onclick and retrieve on load complete.

EX: 
`Session("whichTab") = myTabControl.activetabindex` on click and
`whatever = Session("whichTab")` on load complete for curent page.

NOTE: I do all of this in VB.net code behind

this will tell you when the user changes tabs which one was he or she previously at. Naturally, you would have to find the best way to do this for your app and seeing how the tab controls tabs don't seem to have a serverside click event, I do the multiview instead. If someone can correct me on the click event please do. I haven't really looked at the specs for the control though I just started using it and is how I got here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Would you mind sharing a bit of the code. I am glad to see/hear about solutions in the native language, rather than plugging in, rapping, or using java script or jquery or something else, to solve what can be done in the native lang. BIG Vote up. I realize sometimes other langs are required, and in a few cases makes some things easier. But I always try to stay in the native lang.